# Reach optimal values by not decreasing gradient

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

Is it possible to reach the optimal values ​​for the parameters by not applying the decreasing gradient in some layers?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How will you set initial value of the kernel in the layer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question is whether it's possible to randomly initialize some layers in a neural network and not apply gradient descent to them.

I believe the answer is yes. In synthesizer, they use a random matrix in the "attention layer" and did not train them, and still achieved reasonable results. Though I'm not sure how "optimal" that is. See here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.00743

I'm sure this applies to other networks (e.g. CNNs) as well. Is there a particular application you have in mind for this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).